# MySQL: Can't update a single record based on an autoincremented key

Tags: mysql, tags

I have a table called "data" that is very simple. It has 2 columns: "key"and "tagged". "Key" is an autoincremented id.

I am trying to update the "tagged" column depending on the "key". I am using this very simple query:

UPDATE data SET tagged='Blahblahblah' WHERE key='1';

However, MySQL gives me the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key='1'' at line 1

I don't understand what the problem is with my query. Would you have any idea?

Jean-Nicolas

Answer (score 4):

`key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and must be escaped with back ticks.

```
UPDATE data SET tagged='Blahblahblah' WHERE `key`='1';
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the `key` column is an `auto increment` column. I am sure it is either of type `int` or `bigint`.

So you should not use  in the `WHERE` clause also the word `key` is a reserved keyword.

Try -

```
UPDATE data SET tagged='Blahblahblah' WHERE `key`=1;
```

Comment: 99% sure it's throwing the error because `key` is not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes around the 1 and put it around key, since its a keyword. Make it **'key' = 1**

That should do the trick.